# how to have li in ul align to left with zero space, and all li display vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code

```
<ul style="text-align:left;width: 100px;height: 300px; overflow-y:scroll; list-style: none;list-style-position:inside;">
// li will be dynamically insert by JQuery
    <li> <img src="xxxx">1</img></li>
    <li> <img src="xxxx">2</img></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
IMG1
IMG2
```

however, the actual output is:

```
{Some Space}IMG1
{Some Space}IMG2
```

anyone know what should I do, to have the image have zero space to the left?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is caused by padding on the ul.  You'll need to add `padding-left: 0` to your styles

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the padding and margin to `0px` for `li`?